# PowerShell's Invoke-Expression missing param

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I thought that I had the latest CTP of PowerShell 2 but when I try the command:

`invoke-expression –computername Server01 –command 'get-process PowerShell'`

I get an error message:
**A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'computername'.**

So the question is: How can I tell which version of PowerShell I have installed? And what the latest version is?

Answer (score 3):

From last night's build (which means you might have this in CTP3 but if not, you'll get it in the next public drop):

```
[4120:0]PS> $psversiontable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.3521
BuildVersion                   6.1.7047.0
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.0
```

Experiment! Enjoy! Engage!

Jeffrey Snover [MSFT]
Windows Management Partner Architect

Answer (score 2):

`$host.version.tostring()` will return the version number.

RTM of v1 is 1.0.0.0

Couldn't honestly tell you what the latest version of the previews are because I haven't had a chance to play yet.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that from CTP 1 to CTP2, they switched up the Invoke stuff, all the remoting stuff is done through `Invoke-Command` now, and `Invoke-Expression` is solely for turning a string into a script ;)

P.S.: If you're on v2 you can run `$PSVersionTable` to see a list of versions including the CLR and Build versions.

Answer (score 1):

The latest CTP is CTP2 released on 05/02/08 and can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=7C8051C2-9BFC-4C81-859D-0864979FA403&displaylang=en).  Remoting requires WinRM to be installed on both the calling machine and the target machine.  Included in the CTP is a script to configure WS-Management called Configure-WSMan.ps1.

This command should get you the version number of PowerShell that you have installed.
Get-Command "$PSHome\powershell.exe" | Format-List FileVersionInfo
V1.0 is 6.0.5430.0
CTP2 is 6.1.6585.1

I don't have the version number for the first CTP on hand, but I can find it if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is a change to the cmdlet made during the configuration process Configure-Wsman.ps1.  I don't have an environment setup to test right now, but I'm guessing something went wrong with the configuration.  I can verify that on XP the parameter is not available (duh).  I'd assume that you will find the same on Vista/08 without the configuration completed.

Answer (score 0):

If the `$PSVersionTable` variable doesn't exist, then you are running V1.

If it exists, then the version will be available as `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`.

```
function Get-PSVersion {  
    if (test-path variable:psversiontable) 
        {$psversiontable.psversion} 
    else 
        {[version]"1.0.0.0"}  
}
```